# Finding the location of series of text in series of another text

Tags: python, pandas, search

I want to search ser1 A column values in ser2 C column and find the location of  B column text in corresponding D column text. ser2 is database I'm looking at and I want to save the order ser1 but just locations of text.

```
ser1
A         B
"aa"    "xy"
"ac"    "ztb"
"aa"    "tx"
nan     "yzb"


ser2
C         D
"aa"     "txyzan"
"bc"     "axyz"
"ac"     "fyztb"
```

I tried to change index of ser1 and ser2 as A and C columns and search in them but there are more than 1 nan and "aa" values so I get  TypeError: must be str, not Series.

```
y=[]


for x in ser1.A:
y.append(ser2.loc[x,"D"].find(ser1.loc[x,"B"]))
```

As a result I want to obtain a list like [1, 2, 0, nan]. So if anyone can help I would be glad.
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: I added my attempt and normally when I ask, I always put my attempts, but it wasn't that good, so I didn't add. I didn't get what I did wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know pandas, instead I prepared the solution with base python. A dataframe `ser1` is `[["aa", "ac", "aa", ""],["xy", "ztb", "tx", "yzb"]]`; `ser2` is also mutated accordingly.

Assuming you have the same number of rows for all columns of ser1 and ser2:

```
y=list()
for x in range(len(ser1[0])):
    if ser1[0][x]=="": 
        y.append(float('nan'))
    else:
        y.append(ser2[1][ser2[0].index(ser1[0][x])].index(ser1[1][x]))
```

This might solve your problem, if I did not misunderstand you. Since I used index method, the code will always find the first occurrence of the `aa`. Also please note that you can mutate the data frame to lists of list by:

```
ser1_list = ser1.values.tolist()
```

After the code chunk above, you can remutate to the data frame of pandas by:

```
result = pandas.DataFrame(y)
```